# How to commit a transaction on multiple sql queries in Rx-java2 jdbc?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to insert sql records into multiple records with rxjava2-jdbc. Please let me know how can I achieve that. I tried below steps but it was unsuccessful.

Case 1)

```
public class DatabaseRepository {

    private Database db;

    public DatabaseRepository() throws Exception{

        NonBlockingConnectionPool pool =
                Pools.nonBlocking()
                        .maxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 5)
                        .connectionProvider(ConnectionProvider.from("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//rcld19-scan.test.com:1522/TGCD01", "test", "testPassword"))
                        .build();

        this.db = Database.from(pool);

    }

        public Flowable<Integer> insertIntoMultipleTables() {

               Flowable<Integer> insertIntoEmployee=db.update(insert into employee(name, designation) values ("Employee_1","Manager"))
                    .counts()
                    .doOnError(e -> {
                        log.error("Exception while inserting record to employee table: {}", e.getMessage());
                    });

               return db.update(insert into department(name, no_of_employees) values("Management",1))
                    .dependsOn(insertIntoEmployee)
                    .counts()
                    .doOnError(e -> {
                        log.error("Exception while inserting record to department table: {}", e.getMessage());
                    });
        }
}
```

I am trying to insert into multiple tables as part of a single transaction. In this case, failure on insertion of record into department table will not rollback data from first table

Case 2)

```
public class DatabaseRepository {

    private Database db;

    public DatabaseRepository() throws Exception{

        NonBlockingConnectionPool pool =
                Pools.nonBlocking()
                        .maxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 5)
                        .connectionProvider(ConnectionProvider.from("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//rcld19-scan.test.com:1522/TGCD01", "test", "testPassword"))
                        .build();

        this.db = Database.from(pool);

    }
    public Flowable<Tx<Integer>> insertIntoMultipleTables(){

            Flowable<Tx<Integer>>  insertIntoEmployee= db.update(insert into employee(name, designation) values ("Employee_1","Manager"))             
                    .transacted()
                    .counts()
                    .flatMap(tx ->{
                        return tx.update(insert into department(name, no_of_employees) values("Management",1))
                                .counts()
                                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Exception while inserting record to department table: {}",
                                        e.getMessage()));

                    })
                    .doOnError(e -> {
                        log.error("Exception while inserting record to employee table: {}", e.getMessage());
                    });

        }
}
```

This code is not working as a transaction. Any SQL error in one of the insertion, is not rolling back the records inserted into other table

My requirement is using reactive java2-jdbc i need to insert records into multiple database tables, I am not able to find any valid examples in Git.  Please let me know if I need to do anything differently.

Comment: When you say "not working", what is the symptom? Where do you subscribe to your observer chains?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have updated the code. I am not able to insert records into multiple database table as a single transaction. Any failure in inserting records into one of the table is not rolling back records that was inserted into other table. Please let me know if I need to do anything differently.

Comment: @ravikiran, Did you find any solution for this. I'm stuck on the same thing since long.